# Is multi-lines description supported by `tqdm.set_description()`

Tags: python, tqdm

I find that `tqdm.set_description()` may not support multi-lines string, as

```py
with tqdm(range(10), file=sys.stdout) as t:
    for i in t:
        t.set_description(f"info\n{i}")
>>>
info
info
info
info
info
info
info
info
info
info
info
9: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 37150.61it/s]
```

So, how to solve this problem?

Your answer and guide will be appreciated!